# CSS & jQuery : slideshow not... sliding

Tags: jquery, html, css

as I was trying to do a slideshow with the help of CSS and jQuery (actually ripped it off a tutorial..), i realized that only the last picture is showing, and the slideshow is not "rotating"
I have the css:

```
#home{
    color: #e3e3e3;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 30%;
    width: 30%;
    position: relative;
    top: 5%;
    opacity: 1;
    text-align: justify;}
#slideshow {
    margin: 0px auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 2%;
    width: 500px;
    height: 350px;
    padding: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);}
#slideshow > div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;}
```

the jQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();
  setInterval(function() {
    $("#slideshow > div:first")
      .fadeOut(1000)
      .next()
      .fadeIn(1000)
      .end()
      .appendTo("#slideshow");
  },3000);
}
```

and the html :

```
<div id="home">
<div id="slideshow">
<div>
    <img src="./images/mulsanne.jpg" title="Black Mulsanne by ProTech" alt="Black Mulsanne" style="height:350px;width=500px"/>
</div>
<div>
    <img src="./images/murcielago.jpg" title="Orange Lamborghini Murcielago by ProTech" alt="Orange Murcielago" style="height:350px;width=500px"/>
</div>
<div>
    <img src="./images/BrabusK8.jpg" title="Black Brabus K8 by ProTech" alt="Black K8" style="height:350px;width=500px"/>
</div>
<div>
    <img src="./images/superleggera.jpg" title="Grey Lamborghini Superleggera by ProTech" alt="Grey Superleggera" style="height:350px;width=500px"/>
</div>
<div>
    <img src="./images/slr.jpg" title="Black Mercedes SLR by ProTech" alt="Black SLR" style="height:350px;width=500px"/>
</div>
</div>
<br>
Represented in more than XX countries, and exclusive distributor in Kazakhstan since 2009, ProTech's aim is to offer the best services in terms of car paint protection and windows enhancements, with exclusive Kevlar-coated films with various effects.<br>
Find more about us by clicking on the 2 buttons on the left side of this webpage !
</div>
```

(the last lines of text are under the slideshow, it's just to show you the reason why i have a div id'ed "#home")

any idea why this is not working??

Comment: could it be that you allways select the same elements? <-- `$("#slideshow > div:first")`

Comment: what do you mean? i think i select the first because each time i put the previous one at the end...no? =p)

Comment: always show your code in jsfiddle.net

Comment: Its working fine ..here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/

Just changed  = to : inside inline style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to work fine here http://jsfiddle.net/yRJ2e/

You have syntax errors in your image tag style- width uses "=" and should be ":"

```
 style="height:350px;width=500px"
```

Should be:

```
 style="height:350px;width:500px"
```

Comment: yep didn't see that typo...didn't solve the problem but at least solved something else.. =)

Comment: ok here it is : http://jsfiddle.net/erDWz/       there's a bunch of other stuff, that does other jquery things (that actually work, don't pay attention to them), but here we can clearly see that the slides are not moving (the numbers on the slides are one on top of the others...). make the "result" window as big as you can..

Comment: you have syntax error...use a console to debug. Misisng closing brace on ready function. Works fine

Comment: dear lord am i retarded.. long day of (trying to) work... thanks a lot, charlietfl!!